# How can I print a specific variable from a command's output using grep?

Tags: text-processing, grep

test.txt file:

```
Ext Temperatur:  210.0°
Avg.Speed(All):    62.89mm/s
Avg.Speed(Print):  49.99mm/s
Avg.Speed(Travel): 199.84mm/s
Overall Time (w/o Acceleration): 11:00:41 (39640.65sec)
```

How can I grab `62.89mm/s` and `62.89` as outputs using `grep` and print with php code?

I am using this code but it prints the whole line e.g.: `Avg.Speed(All):    62.89mm/s`

```
<?php
$gcode_new = "grep -P 'Avg.Speed(All):' test.txt";

include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('XXX.61.XXX.227');
if (!$ssh->login('root', 'PASS')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}
$target = $ssh->exec($gcode_new);

echo $target ;
?>
```

**Question Update:** How can i copy 11:00:41 from above data which is associated with "Overall Time (w/o Acceleration):" Tried to use the command which is suggested from answer, but receiving `11:00:41 (39640.65sec)` here how can i avoid `(39640.65sec)`.
`$ grep -Po '(?<=Overall Time \(w/o Acceleration\):   ).*' testjar.txt`

Comment: What operating system are you using? Do you have the GNU implementation of grep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use positive lookbehind assertion with GNU grep:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=Avg.Speed\(All\):    ).*' test.txt
62.89mm/s
$ grep -Po '(?<=Avg.Speed\(All\):    )[0-9\.]+' test.txt
62.89
```

Comment: Here i need to copy 11:00:41

Comment: @testcod You are now changing the input data. Update your question or ask a new one. We don't really like follow-up questions in comments.

Comment: @Kusalananda Updated question, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed` to grab `62.89mm/s` from the example data by matching and deleting the start of the line:

```
sed -n 's/^Avg\.Speed(All):[[:blank:]]*//p' test.txt
```

To also strip the `mm/s` units off from the end (this strips any non-digits from the end):

```
sed -n '/^Avg\.Speed(All):[[:blank:]]*/{s///;s/[^[:digit:]]*$//p;}' test.txt
```

---

For the update question:

```
sed -n 's/^Overall Time.*\(..:..:..\).*/\1/p' file
```

This would extract the time string from the line starting with `Overall Time` in your data.

Comment: @testcod Use a simple command substitution?  `value=$(sed -n ...)`

Comment: `$jarext_5 = "sed -n 's/^Overall Time.*\(..:..:..\).*/\1/p' testjar.txt";` received `   ` as output

Comment: @testcod See my previous comment.